# extract files from disk image (paragon and partitionmanager)

Tags: restore, paragon, partitionmanager

I've backed up my drive with the two tools in the title, now i want to extract some files from it (not a complete restore). how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try using 7-Zip or Universal Extractor. If it is using a standard compression algorithym, it should work.